# Ruby AES encryption

Tags: .net, ruby, encryption, aes

I am migrating a webservice/database written in Microsoft .net framework to ruby. I am stuck at the password encryption part because I can't replicate the encryption on ruby side. Here's the code that generates an encrypted password in .net:

```
    private static String GetSecret()
    {
        string nexus = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Nexus"];
        System.Security.SecureString plain = ProtectedSettings.DecryptString(nexus);
        return ProtectedSettings.ToInsecureString(plain);
    }

    private static String EncryptPassword(string password)
    {
        return SymmetricEncryption.Encrypt<AesManaged>(password, GetSecret());
    }
```

I got the string named `nexus`and in ruby, using the aes gem, I did:

```
AES.encrypt(a_password, key)
```

but the generated hash doesn't match the one in .net. What am I missing? thanks

Here's the Encrypt function:

```
public static string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password, string salt = "4AFB7A1414E4486FAB51A42F5D0D6E7B")
             where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {
            DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));

            SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();

            byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
            byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);

            ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);

            using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        writer.Write(value);
                    }
                }

                return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

Ok so I have tried converting this code to ruby, but with no luck:

```
p = PBKDF2.new(:password => pass, :salt => salt, :iterations => 1000)  
iv = p.hash_function.digest[0..15]
key = p.hash_function.digest[0..31]
aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-128-CBC")
aes.encrypt
aes.key = key
aes.iv = iv 
aes.update("1123581321") + aes.final
```

Comment: You have not even touched the part for PBKDF2 (`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`) it seems. Maybe read up on cryptography first. Then *start* with the key derivation part.

Comment: @owlstead I did that but with no luck. Can you please take a look at my attempt at this in ruby?

Comment: If your key *is* 32 bytes then I presume you have to use AES-256. The 256 in AES is the key size, so `256 / 8 = 32`... First compare the derived key values (in hex), then go on with the AES part...

Answer (score 3):

There are several things which could be going on.

1. You could be using a different cipher block padding scheme
2. You could be using a different key size
3. Your initialisation vector for the AES engine could be different.
4. Your key could be incorrect
5. Your plaintext could be in a different character set

You need to establish the settings used during encryption in your .Net environment, then you need to replicate these in your ruby environment.

[Getting incorrect decryption value using AesCryptoServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937707/getting-incorrect-decryption-value-using-aescryptoserviceprovider/) touches on the use of the initialization vector (IV) in .net

http://developer.mintrus.com/2011/08/aes-encryption-in-ruby-on-rails/ gives a brief tutorial on AES in ruby (specifically in rails, but it is applicable to your situation

Comment: Thanks for the input. The IV is generate by 'ICryptoTransform' which I have no idea what it is. I posted the details in my original question, can you please take a look?

Comment: @0xSina your IV is in your encrypt block : `byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);` - establish what the byte values are in this array and use them in your ruby encrypt function's IV

Comment: I did that, but with no luck. Can you please take a look at my attempt at this in ruby?

Comment: @Trip nop. It's been a while, but luckily the password weren't hashed, just encrypted. So I decrypted them using .NET framework, and then hashed them using Ruby and then entered them into my db.

Comment: @0xSina So your Ruby app used a .net framework to decrypt the AES? I think I'm having a similar issue where the AES strings are being encrypted in Microsoft, and for some reason, Mac OS X or Ruby doesn't understand the same binary/variables/etc.

Comment: @Trip no. The app was written in .NET framework. I rewrote the app in Rails, an migrated the DB over from MSSQL to MySQL. The only issue was  the passwords were encrypted using some .NET library and I couldn't replicate it in Ruby. So using the same .NET library that encrypted the, i decrypted them, and rehashed them using Ruby and fed them into my new DB.